# PHP thinks null is 0 when I do strpos

Tags: php

PHP is thinking that null is 0 when the character in $position doesn't exist.

> $statusentery = $_POST[status];
>
> $position = strpos($statusentery,"<");
>
> if ($position == 0){
> echo "Sorry, for security purposes we do not
> allow characters such as <";
>
> exit;
>
> }

For example, if $statusentery was equal to "Howdy there", it would return "Sorry, for security purposes we do not allow characters such as <". (unexpected)

If $statusentery was equal to "Howdy there <"  it would return blank (expected).

How to make it work so that when I enter "Howdy there", it didn't do the if loop, but when I enter "< howdy there>", it did the if loop?

Comment: `Warning
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because 0 can means "false" in PHP, $postition will be false when it doesn't exist.  So you'll need to use the following:

```
if ($position === 0){
```

Using the triple equal sign in PHP verifies that the compared values have the same data type.  A lot more information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2):

From: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php

> WARNING
>
> As strpos may return either FALSE (substring absent) or 0 (substring
>   at start of string), strict versus loose equivalency operators must be
>   used very carefully.
>
> To know that a substring is absent, you must use:
>
> === FALSE
>
> To know that a substring is present (in any position including 0), you
>   can use either of:
>
> !== FALSE  (recommended)
>
> > -1  (note: or greater than any negative number)
>
> To know that a substring is at the start of the string, you must use:
>
> === 0
>
> To know that a substring is in any position other than the start, you
>   can use any of:
>
> > 0  (recommended) != 0  (note: but not !== 0 which also equates to FALSE) != FALSE  (disrecommended as highly confusing)
>
> Also note that you cannot compare a value of "" to the returned value
>   of strpos. With a loose equivalence operator (== or !=) it will return
>   results which don't distinguish between the substring's presence
>   versus position. With a strict equivalence operator (=== or !==) it
>   will always return false.

So the code must be:

```
$statusentery = $_POST[status];
$position = strpos($statusentery,"<");

if ($position === 0){
echo "Sorry, for security purposes we do not allow characters such as <";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky function. As stated in the strpos manual:

> Warning This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to false. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
> return value of this function.

I use this comparison, which works well without even a notice level warning:

```
if ($position > -1)
```

Returns boolean false when the string is not found, which is evaluable as a number, thus comparing whether the value is greater than -1 actually works well. In case any match is found, even at position 0 the above comparison will be passed.